# Push Node-red flows to Gitlab Automatically

Tags: git, gitlab, node-red

Is there anyway to create a project in Gitlab (using nodes) and then push my flows to it every time i deploy knowing that my Node-red is in a docker container ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not with the built in Projects feature, you have to manually decide when to push changes to the default git repo. This is deliberate as it allows you to test things and then decide what to check in, it also allows for collecting meaningful commit messages about what has changed and why.

There a 2 possible ways to approach this.

1. Write a custom storage plugin that will push the flow on each deploy. The API for the storage API an be found [here](https://nodered.org/docs/api/storage/). You would need to create a custom Docker container that included the plugin.
2. Some people have included the logic in their flows, and used a inject node set to fire on start to grab the flow and check it into git. There is a post on the forum with an example [here](https://discourse.nodered.org/t/project-mode-by-tabs-flow/39864) that you may be able to adapt. But since it appears to be using the Admin API, it won't be able to check in credentials.

Comment: Thanks for your response ! i've already found this post on the node red forum and i tried to integrate it in my work flow but it didn't work because there is no documentation so it's quite difficult to figure out how it works. Actually i'm new to Node red so i didn't heard about storage plugins before, but it seems to be a good solution. thank you very much for your help again i really appreciate it